# Database unique keys, JPA repositories and getByUniqueKey signatures: how does it works?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, unique-index

**Background**

Datatable `item`:

```
+---------+---------+--------+
|  field  |  type   | index  |
+---------+---------+--------+
| id_item | INT     | PK     |
| name    | VARCHAR | UNIQUE |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

`ItemRepository.java`:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CustomRepository<Item, Integer> {
    public Item getByName(String name); // because of the unique index
}
```

`CustomRepository.java`:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomRepository<E, PK extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<E, PK>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {
    // common methods
}
```

`CustomRepositoryImpl.java`:

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl<E, PK extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<E, PK> implements CustomRepository<E, PK> {
    // common methods implementations
}
```

**Question**

As you can see, there isn't no implementation of the interface `ItemRepository`. Which means, the `getByName` method has just a signature and never get implemented at anywhere. But it works. How?

**PS**

For the skeptics, with Eclipse, when keeping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed and the mouse over the `getByName` signature, clicking on `Open Implementation` doesn't open any JAVA file at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses AOP for repositories, and will intercept any `getByX` method where `X` matches a bean property.  In your example, the `Item` bean, declares the `name` property, so Spring intercepts it for you.

See [Defining query methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) in the [Spring Data JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) manual.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work also with `findByX` instead of `getByX`?

Comment: Yep: `findBy`, `find`, `readBy`, `read`, `getBy` and `get` all work.